# Why does the area under the curve tell us anything about the function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I apologize in advance for such a naïve question, but I am learning about integrals right now, and something keeps gnawing at me!

So if we take the definite integral of a function  $f'(x)$ over the interval say $[2,5]$, what we are really doing (and how I like to think of it) is summing all of the outputs of the antiderivative function $f(x)$ over the interval $[2,5]$ where every "item" added to the "set of items to sum" is the output from $f(x)$ with an infinitesimally small increase in the previous $x$.

So in my head I see taking the integral as summing the values in the region highlighted purple on $f(x)$ for:
[image]

And not as the area under the curve of the derivative function $f'(x)$:

[image]

I see this as the "correct" way personally because I am unable to make the connection of what the "area under the curve" really is, besides empty space that our function does not interact with.

Edit for @Dheeraj: In the images below you can see my miss-understanding, they are there to show my previous **wrong** thinking. I thought that the rectangles would continue splitting until there were no more `x` values left, and converge to only a `y` values. But this would not make sense because every time a rectangle gets "smaller" another rectangle appears, it is not as if there are a finite number of rectangles whos widths continue getting smaller. New rectangles are infinitely constructed, which means new `y` values are constructed too. Also note that they are split up, but it goes from left to right.

Added image that better shows my misunderstanding:
[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150060/discussion-on-question-by-zenpyro-why-does-the-area-under-the-curve-tell-us-anyt); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is Arc Length. If $\int$ is the area under the curve, the arc length of $f(x)$ from $x=x_0$ to $x=x_1$ would be $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\text{ dx}$ where $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ evaluated at each point $x_0 \le x \le x_1$. So essentially, the arc length of the curve $f(x)$ is secretly equal to the area under a transformed version of $f'$.

Area under curve, when the curve is lying in $[-1, +1]$, is a richer class than arc length since arc-length only increases, and is always non-negative. Whereas area under a curve can go negative if your $f$ is negative in enough mass to outweigh the positive mass encountered that far in your definite integral.. Hope that clears it up a bit, basically area under a curve has to be defined before one is able to comprehend the arc length, and the arc length is a specialized subset of all possible areas under curves, so it is not enough to consider only arc lengths.

Comment: Wow, way to swoop in last minute and clear up hours of confusion! This is incredible! I have a few follow up questions if you don't mind answering!

Comment: Of course if it is pertinent to your original question you should ask it here as a reply

Comment: So let's say you have a function $f(x)$ that is monotonically increasing (say $f(x) = x^3$ for values $0<x$, and the derivative of that function is $f'(x)$. Is your answer saying that the "Arc Length" of $f'(x)$ is not equivalent to the "area under the curve" of itself, $f'(x)$, but instead the function $f''(x)$?

Comment: the arc length of $x^3$ from $0$ to $x$ would be the area under the curve $\sqrt{9x^4+1}$ between $0$ and $x$, since $f'(x) = 3x^2$, and using the formula in the answer. But the integral of $x^3$ from $0$ to $x$ is simply the polynomial function $x^4/4$. The integral of that $\sqrt \cdot$ curve written above is NOT a polynomial, and cannot be written in any simpler form.

Comment: There is a wikipedia section you can read more about this here it seems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integration

Comment: Great! Also, I have heard many differing ideas when I ask this question (and I want to ask you and see what you say), but is there any possible way to find the "area under the curve" of a function $f'(x) = x^2$, if we are not allowed to take the anti-derivative $f(x)$? Basically what everything comes down to is: I want to know if I could still find the "area under a curve" if integrals were snapped out of existence? And I do not mean Riemann-sums, but exacts, as integrals give us.

Comment: even though your "arc length" point is correct, I disagree with *"basically area under a curve is more useful of a definition...."*, Because you cannot find arc length using integral before even defining what integral means, So "area" definition was not a choice

Comment: @ZenPyro, Just a quick question, Do you know the order in which these things were formulated? I think that would clear up a lot of your doubts

Comment: yeah it's not more useful it just has to be area it basically couldn't be arc length so I should do another edit, thanks..

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Yea so I am watching a great video right now, where he is proving the fundamental theorem of calculus, but without mentioning anything that the theorem gives us after it is proved. It's helping me realize that the area was found first.

Answer (score 1):

Even If it seems correct to you, the flaw lies  When you say the integral of derivative function is same as summation of values of all points of that curve, It is incorrect, Because as you intuitively know that derivative is rate of change, i. e small change in $y$ over small change in $x$ or $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, When you do the intgeral of the derivative, It is same as saying, Adding all the small changes of the initial functions, not adding all the $values$ of initial function, So the integral gives change in function, Not summation of all values of function

which means the sum is for example like

$S=f(2+t)-f(2)+f(2+2t)-f(2+t)+f(2+3t)-f(2+2t).............f(5)-f(5-t)$, which yeilds $f(5)-f(2)$ as a result

Now , again very roughly, This is nowhere rigorous, But multiply and divide by $t$ on $R.H.S$  of sum $S$ we get

$S=\left(\frac{f(2+t)-f(2)}{t}+\frac{f(2+2t)-f(2+t)}{t}+\frac{f(2+3t)-f(2+2t)}{t}.............+\frac{f(5)-f(5-t)}{t}\right)t$

now when you take limit $t \to 0$, $t\to dt$

The sum is

$f(5)-f(2)=S=(f'(2)+f'(2+t)+f'(2+2t).............f'(5))dt$

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had exams. Such a good response! I think you got to the heart of my misconception! I see now! For example, I completely blanked on the idea that your initial function could be $f(x) = 5$ and so then your derivative would be $f'(x) = 0$ which means that there is ZERO rate-of-change between the y-values (outputs) of the initial function, but if I did my "add all the outputs of the initial function" approach, then I would get the totally wrong answer!

Comment: But now I have two other questions, if you don't mind helping me a little more. This might sound really silly, but if we know the average rate-of-change is $\frac{f(b)−f(a)}{b−a}$ where the numerator is change and the denominator is "how long it took" (maybe interval of change is more mathematical), then if you wanted to find the EXACT rate-of-change, wouldn't you just take the numerator?

Comment: AND YES, before you say it, I know that $f(5)−f(2) = \int_{2}^{5} f'(x) \,dx$ but as in, why was there a need for "area under the curve" to be found, when there was another method for finding the same value (in a more intuitive way)? Or am I being too closeminded, and noticing that its not about being able to get the "area under the curve" per say, but more about how the integral truly connects the initial function $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ mathematically.

Comment: It shows the intermediate step between the two. Without it, the connection between the two would be much more vague. So it's less about the output of the integral, and more about allowing us to peer inside the "black box" of the relationship between the function of rate-of-change and the function of "magnitude" (I dont know how I would say that). **My second question is:**  So you are saying that it is possible to find the same value given from the "area under the curve" of $f'(x)$, if you only have $f'(x)$ and cannot get the antiderivative.

Comment: This would be done by summing all the y-values between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ and not the (like I wrongly said earlier) y-values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. So this is where I am still a little confused. So let's say you are making rectangles with infinitely small width and the y-value as the height, to model the area under the curve of $f'(x)$. Your width is going to keep getting smaller and smaller, so let's say you reach the end of infinity and see what your rectangles theoretically "look" like. Wouldn't they have a width of $0$ and only a non-zero height (that being the y-value).

Comment: So if you add up all of the areas of all of the rectangles "at the end of infinity", then you're really just adding up the heights, which is really just the infinite amount of y-values of $f'(x)$ between $[a,b]$. So I do not see the point of calling it an "area" when it's really just the "heights".

Comment: So are $$\sum_{x=a}^{b} f'(x_i)  \text{and} \space \int_a^b f'(x)dx$$ the same? Where $x$ in the summation increases by an infinitesimal amount $i$ in each incrementation.

Comment: @ZenPyro,For your last comment,no, Absolutely not, the integral is indeed area because you are adding all $f'(x) dx$ not only $f'(x)$, See $R.H.S$ of my rough value of $S$ in the answer, It might seem at last to be adding the values of all $f'(t)$, but notice small $dt$ at the end, Because $45 \ dt \neq 45$ and for all such values of $f'(x)$, $f'(x)dx \neq f'(x)$

Comment: Ahhh so we never actually reach $0$ we just are infinitely getting close to it, and this is why there is no way to make a finite summation that say "okay at last we made $x$ as small as possible"

Comment: @ZenPyro, I don't understand your last comment about "There is no way....."

Comment: I made an edit to the bottom of my question, so you can hopefully see where my thinking went wrong. I couldn't scale down the images so they are split in two.

Comment: See I thought that integration was equivalent to summing an infinite number of integrals that look like so:  $$\int_{c}^{c} f'(x) \,dx$$ This would give you no area under the curve because they have no area (no width), and `dx` made me think that we reached a point as such, at some point, but we never have `dx = 0`.

Comment: @ZenPyro, Though $dx$ approaches $0$, such number of all $f'(x)dx$ takes infinite number of sums, Giving a finite value, and This finite value is also justified by squeeze theoram of Upper and lower bound of area, Now regarding your image, You said " there is no width to multiply with,So only length is left", Even If there is small width $dx$, When multiplied by length $f(x)$, Such area $f(x)dx$ is very very small, And All such accumulation of such very small areas for tending to infinite number of Such area is what gives us our definite integral

Comment: YES! I understand perfectly now! Thank you for the help! When I first opened this question, I thought, "Area does not matter because you do not need $x$ to find the same value that area under the curve gives". But you really do need area, because you are not and WILL NEVER sum just the $y$-values, you are always summing a PRODUCT of $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150091/discussion-between-dheeraj-gujrathi-and-zenpyro).

Answer (score -4):

I know a teacher who can figure out x approaches zero in derivatives if you want me to look through it.  Off the top of my head I would say you need more graphs to explain how the integration works rather than calculating without the approaches <-- x equation.

I will clarify a little further.  You need to Sum with x and y on the graph. *f′* can be shown on the following graph as you said first.  The idea is that with the sum of the numbers in the highlight, the area still will not help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM3cA.png

*S* = *f* dy/dx helps because (d - t) and (d - h) reveals exactly how the function box summarizes the 2 and 5 values are clearer than just